# nohup or persistent process on Mac OS X ssh

Tags: macos, terminal

I know this has been asked before but none of the answers seems to work in OS X Mountain Lion. I would like to launch a process via SSH and close the terminal without killing the process.

```
nohup ccl64 -e '(ql:quickload :"file")' &
```

Doesn't work. When the terminal is closed, the process dies.

```
nohup ccl64 -e '(ql:quickload :"file")'
```

Same here.

I think there must be a way. This is very annoying as it works as a standard in any Linux system, yet Mac OS X refuses to work with any of these combinations.

Answer (score 12):

One thing that always works is `screen`. http://ss64.com/osx/screen.html it seems to be available on Mac OS X per default.

Edit: http://web.archive.org/web/20130413070916/http://macdevcenter.com/pub/a/mac/2004/07/06/unix_gems.html another tutorial abut screen.

Additionally, here is some quick tips on how to use `screen`

Open a new 'screen' instance

```
$ screen
```

Once, in the screen, you can 'detach' (or close out of it) the screen like this:

```
ctrl+A and then press D
```

To resume a screen, you typically do this:

```
$ screen -x
```

If you have *more than one* screen instance, it will tell you their IDs, in which case you can choose which one to **resume** like this:

```
$ screen -r <screen id>
```

Comment: so over ssh I do screen and then pass the nohup command? with or without the & at the end ?

Comment: No need for `nohup`. Just do screen ccl64... & . Later, if you need to you can reconnect with screen -R to monitor progress. Alternatively, just run screen and type the command in there , you can detach with Ctrl+A D.

Comment: thanks it is possible to save the screen output in a file after the launch ?

Comment: Of course, screen can do everything. You want screen -X `hardcopy`. See https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=47521 for more.

Answer (score 6):

Try `screen` instead, it should still be part of the default install. Some people [even use screen as their default shell](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20021114055617124) so they don't need to worry about nohup at all.

Comment: could you describe how to run a nohup command with screen?

Comment: You use screen instead of nohup, and then detach the screen. Your program will continue to work even if the ssh session ends.

Comment: See `man screen` for details.